# Aligning ListBoxItem content

Tags: .net, wpf, listbox

I am trying to align the content of a `ListBoxItem`. In the example below I want to have the `TextBlock` left aligned and the `Button` right aligned in each row of the ListBox. But the Button always follows directly after the end of the TextBlock's text and isn't right aligned in the ListBox.

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataList}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeTextProperty}" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
                    <Button Content="Display" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5"
                        Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Something needs to be changed in my XAML, I guess. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Only have a few minutes or I would post code, but you can put the items in a DockPanel instead of a StackPanel (using Dock Left and Right respectively) and then set HorizontalContentAlignment on the ListBox to Stretch.

Comment: @Dan Bryant: Thanks for the guidance. The DockPanel solution also works fine. I only noticed that I have to define a fixed Width of the Button, otherwise each Button stretches from the end of the TextBlock's text to the right border of the ListBox.

Comment: for future reference, DockPanel has a property LastChildFill that defaults to True, which causes the behavior you observed.  If you set this property to false, the last child will dock as instructed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need a different panel type, but you'll also need to get the content to stretch across the ListBox.  You can either specify it as a ControlTemplate for the ListBoxItem, or use the DataTemplate and set ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment to stretch (+1 to Dan Bryant in his comment under the question for pointing this out).

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeTextProperty}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                            <Button Content="Display" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

or

```
        <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeTextProperty}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                        <Button Content="Display" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: I've chosen your second solution which was the easiest. `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` on the `Grid` wasn't even necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using an other panel instead of a stackpanel.. Grid or dock should do the job pretty nice.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your Grid Width with whatever value :

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="150">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
                           Text="{Binding BusinessProperty}"                          
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                           Margin="5" />
                <Button Grid.Column="1" 
                        Content="Display"                          
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5"                         Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"                         CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
           </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The texblock and the button are going to take just the place they need and the middle grid column will fill the remaining space, "pushing" first and last column to the left and to the right respectively in the amount of space provided by the grid (here 150px)

Comment: Good solution but with one disturbing point: I don't want to specify a fixed width of the grid; it should stretch with the width of the ListBox. The second solution in Mark Synowiec's answer does this exactly. But anyway, thanks for help!